# How to nest objects in HTML <input> names

Tags: html, forms

I want to nest the value of an `<input>` in several objects.

For example `settings.toggles.rankup` = true

But as an input name attribute:

`<input type"checkbox" name="settings[toggles[rankup]]" value="true">`

However it only nests one object deep; is there anyway to go further?

Comment: You need to add it on js way, html only set value as string

Comment: If you want to apply any change to the checkbox checked option then you can use VUE js. It is very lightweight and can use in any page you want, not need any global setting.

Or you can use AnguarJs 1.

Comment: Depending on how you plan on parsing the response you can use the dot-separated format to represent arbitrary object depth, eg: `settings.toggles.rankup`. It is not too difficult to reconstruct this as an object.